# Google ad units (DFP) shows number along with the ad on render. How should I hide that number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to hide that number?

Google ad units (DFP) shows number along with the ad on render. How should I hide that number?
**All the scripts are :**

```
googletag.cmd.push(() => {
        googletag.defineSlot(
        this.props.elem.path,
        this.props.elem.size,
    this.props.elem.id,
    ).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
}

**Body :**
<div id={elem.id} style={{ width: elem.size[0], height: elem.size[1] }}>
    {
       googletag.cmd.push(() => {
           googletag.display(elem.id);
       })
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty easy just create a new component and add the following code

```
componentDidMount() {
  googletag.cmd.push(() => {
    googletag.defineSlot(
      this.props.elem.path,
      this.props.elem.size,
      this.props.elem.id,
      ).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
  }
}

render() {
  <div id={elem.id} />
}
```